# string array; java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, indexoutofboundsexception

I have two classes that basically function as the most simplest database, where the user is supposed to enter a string and the program adds it in the array using a class that holds all the methods. Except that when i enter the first name it gives me java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0. I know this means that no memory is being allocated for the array but i thought i did this in my second class where there is a constructer that defines the size of the array. Im not experienced enough with arrays to fix this debug on my own. Much help would be appreicated!

```
import java.util.*;

    public class TestDatabase {
    //contant value for data base 'size' of array
    public static final int constant = 10;
    public static void main (String[] args){
    //Database object sets the array size to constant value
    Database get = new Database(constant);
    //input stream
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    //varaibles for the count and index; prompt
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter 10 names to add them to the database. Name: " + (count +=               1));
    //while the count is lower than or equal to 10...                                                                                 
    while(count<=10){
        //input stream equal to input
        String input = in.nextLine();
        //if the count equals, stop the loop
        if (count == 10)
        {
            //breaks the loop
            break;
        }
        //prints out the current name
        System.out.print(" Name: " + (count +=1));
        //adds the input to the array
        get.add(index,input);
        //increments index by 1
        index++;
    }
    //prints the array
    get.print(); 
}
```

}

Here is my class with my all my methods:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Database{
//size of array
public int _size;
//array which has a varaible size
String[] userArray = new String[_size];
//contructer for the array size
public Database(int size){
    _size = size;
}
//add method which adds a value to an index of an array
public void add(int index, String name){
   //the values of string is placed into some index of the array
   userArray[index] = name;
}
//print method which prints the contents of the array
public void print(){
    //prints array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userArray));
}
//sort method which sorts the array
public void sort(){
    //sorts the array
    Arrays.sort(userArray);
}
//find method which finds a particular string in any index
public void find(String value){
    Arrays.asList(userArray).contains(value);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ArrayList is never instantiated properly, you need to move it into your constructor so when the new operator is called, then the arraylist is created with the size variable that is passed, so something like this:

```
public Database {
    private String[] data;

    public Database(int size){
        this.data = new String[size];
    }
}
```

With your current code, the array is created before the size is actually given, so it defaults to a size of 0.

Answer (score 0):

userArray init with zero length before your constuctor set _size. Create userArray in constructor.

there next steps performed when you create class:

1. _size init with 0
2. userArray init with zero length array
3. _size init with size value.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as below

```
   String[] userArray;
    public Database(int size){
        _size = size;
        userArray = new String[_size];
    }
```